# Why the slash is added to a particular url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm coming back to you after a problem I'm having with redirects in React, I've decided to resume my project from 0 and I'm still having the same problem..

When I request this page `http://localhost:3000/profil` I am automatically redirected to this same page with a slash at the end of the url, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/profil/`.

Why does the `/` appear automatically at the end of the url `http://localhost:3000/profil/`? I'm not asking anywhere.

For the test, the `Profil` page and the `Home` page are exactly the same and should return the same image, except that only the `Home` page returns the image.

Here is the code I am using

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './styles/index.scss'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './components/Routes';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

src/components/Routes/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../../pages/Home';
import Panier from '../../pages/Panier';
import Profil from '../../pages/Profil';

const index = () => {
    return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path='/profil' element={<Profil />} />
                <Route path='/mes-paniers' element={<Panier />} />
                <Route path='*' element={<Home />} />
            </Routes>
    )
};

export default index;
```

src/pages/Profil

```
import React from 'react';

const Profil = () => {
    return (
        <div className="profil-page">
            <div className="log-container">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img src="./img/log.svg" alt="pic-profil" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Profil;
```

The `Home` page looks like the `Profil` page,

src/pages/Home

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="profil-page">
            <div className="log-container">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img src="./img/log.svg" alt="pic-profil" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

The image is not found on `"/profil/"` while on `"/home"` it is displayed.

I don't understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: `<Route path='/' component={Home} />` , this should work I guess.

Comment: Which question do you want answered? The odd trailing slash, or the image loading? I'm not sure about the slash, but the image is using a relative source URL, so if page is on `"/"` or `"/profil"` it will make a difference. Try to use an absolute path for the image source.

Comment: Hi Bhuwan Adhikari, I tried your code but it shows me the following error: **Matched leaf route at location "/profil/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.**

Comment: hi Drew Reese, well I have the impression that these 2 problems are related, the fact that I cannot go to the /profil page makes my image not display, on the Home page (which is exactly the same as Profil) the image displays without issue and the url displays http://localhost:3000 .
I even tried to duplicate on the Panier page, and the image is displayed

Comment: I don't think they are, but I'm also not able to reproduce the issue you describe here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-the-slash-is-added-to-a-particular-url-e53dsy). Can you create a *running* codeandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: thank you for this code Drew, I don't understand that it doesn't work for me, everything seems the same... I even tried with another browser (Brave) but the slash keeps coming back (still only on the profil page )

Comment: I renamed **<Route path='/profil' element={<Profil />} />**
by **<Route path='/profilexample' element={<Profil />} />** and it works... only the path /profil doesn't work, I don't understand anything

Comment: I just fork your codesandbox, with my configuration and it works, it's just on my computer that it doesn't work, https://codesandbox.io/embed/why-the-slash-is-added-to-a-particular-url-forked-7slgyj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems solved to me. I had to reset the default settings of Google Chrome. I can now load my page /profil and no longer /profil/!

EDIT :
It still doesn't work on Brave browser. Can't get just the url http://localhost:3000/profil . It always sends me /profil/.